# seting text to EditText is yelding runtime exception

Tags: android

```
EditText etFreeText = (EditText)pw.getContentView().findViewById(R.id.etSearch);

btnPopUpSearch.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

etFreeText.setText(freeText_lastSearch.toString());

            });
```

logs:

```
09-02 06:14:51.327: W/Binder(13864): Caught a RuntimeException from the binder stub implementation.
09-02 06:14:51.327: W/Binder(13864): java.lang.NullPointerException
09-02 06:14:51.327: W/Binder(13864):    at android.view.textservice.SpellCheckerSession$SpellCheckerSessionListenerImpl.onGetSentenceSuggestions(SpellCheckerSession.java:430)
09-02 06:14:51.327: W/Binder(13864):    at com.android.internal.textservice.ISpellCheckerSessionListener$Stub.onTransact(ISpellCheckerSessionListener.java:61)
09-02 06:14:51.327: W/Binder(13864):    at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:404)
09-02 06:14:51.327: W/Binder(13864):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
```

Comment: What's line ISpellCheckerSessionListener.java:61? Make sure you have initialized `etFreeText` properly, and `freeText_lastSearch` is not null.

Comment: I have not used any spellchecker service class or listener class and the free_lastSearch is not null

Comment: Strange. Because, logcat says so.. `etFreeText` is initialized correctly? Check its id once in xml.