# SpellCheckerSession error

Tags: java, android

I get this error in my apps. But I did not use `SpellCheckerSession` class in my apps.

```
09-02 06:14:51.327: W/Binder(13864): Caught a RuntimeException from the binder stub implementation.
09-02 06:14:51.327: W/Binder(13864): java.lang.NullPointerException
09-02 06:14:51.327: W/Binder(13864):    at android.view.textservice.SpellCheckerSession$SpellCheckerSessionListenerImpl.onGetSentenceSuggestions(SpellCheckerSession.java:430)
09-02 06:14:51.327: W/Binder(13864):    at com.android.internal.textservice.ISpellCheckerSessionListener$Stub.onTransact(ISpellCheckerSessionListener.java:61)
09-02 06:14:51.327: W/Binder(13864):    at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:404)
09-02 06:14:51.327: W/Binder(13864):
```

Comment: this android internal error.

Comment: how can i solve it?any solution?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25621060/seting-text-to-edittext-is-yelding-runtime-exception

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/textservice/SpellCheckerSession.html

Comment: how did u fix it ?